# PHP MongoDB: wrong index is picked

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection called "records" with tens of millions of documents. It has the following index:

```
{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "added_on" : -1,
            "instance" : 1,
            "invisible" : -1,
            "reviewed" : -1
        },
        "name" : "added_on_index",
        "ns" : "test.records"
    },
```

I am trying to perform the following function, which tries to determine the oldest record which is not reviewed.

```
$collection = $this->mongo->getCollection('records');
$cursor = $collection->find(array('instance' => $instance, 'reviewed' => false), array('added_on' => 1))->sort(array('added_on' => 1))->limit(1);
```

I may be wrong, but I read in the book from which I 've learned MongoDB that this should work - when doing a sort use the sort field as the first field of the index.

However, a different index is chosen as the winning plan:

```
[winningPlan] => Array
                (
                    [stage] => PROJECTION
                    [transformBy] => Array
                        (
                            [added_on] => 1
                        )

                    [inputStage] => Array
                        (
                            [stage] => SORT
                            [sortPattern] => Array
                                (
                                    [added_on] => 1
                                )

                            [limitAmount] => 1
                            [inputStage] => Array
                                (
                                    [stage] => SORT_KEY_GENERATOR
                                    [inputStage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [stage] => FETCH
                                            [inputStage] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [stage] => IXSCAN
                                                    [keyPattern] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [instance] => 1
                                                            [invisible] => 1
                                                            [reviewed] => 1
                                                        )

                                                    [indexName] => module_record_retrieval
                                                    [isMultiKey] => 
                                                    [multiKeyPaths] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [instance] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                            [invisible] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                            [reviewed] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [isUnique] => 
                                                    [isSparse] => 
                                                    [isPartial] => 
                                                    [indexVersion] => 2
                                                    [direction] => forward
                                                    [indexBounds] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [instance] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => [ObjectId('58b28de67289ba94352c90bd'), ObjectId('58b28de67289ba94352c90bd')]
                                                                )

                                                            [invisible] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => [MinKey, MaxKey]
                                                                )

                                                            [reviewed] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => [false, false]
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
```

When trying to add hint('added_on_index') to the find function, even $cursor->explain() gets stuck for what appears to be a huge amount of time.
Any help on solving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Neither look like a good choice considering `invisible` is not mentioned anywhere in your query. I don't see any attempt at adding a "hint" here, perhaps you should show one since "hanging" suggests you are doing something incorrectly. Also, consider the similarity of the two indexes and that you probably don't need both, and could therefore drop one of them. Also note that ["query prefix" takes precedence over "sorting"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index) in the case of index selection.

Comment: Thanks Neil. If logically I first want to sort, then query the sorted index, what would be a proper way to give sorting precedence? both invisible and reviewed are boolean, so it shouldn't impact that much, from what I read.

Comment: Regarding the hint, I use $cursor = $collection->find(array('instance' => $instance, 'reviewed' => false), array('added_on' => 1))->hint('added_on_index')->sort(array('added_on' => 1))->limit(1);
Also tried adding it after the "limit"